# Mac Terminal start up giving error

Tags: macos, error-handling, terminal, terminal-services

Hi guys I am trying to start up my mac Terminal but every time I open the program this error message pops up. I know this can't be good.

```
Last login: Sun Oct  9 17:41:44 on ttys000
-bash: /Users/Perez/.bash_profile: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /Users/Perez/.bash_profile: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Jaimes-MacBook-Pro:~ Perez$
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I am no bash expert but it looks like you have a string missing the end quote ".  Just open the .bash_profile in an editor and look for the error. My guess is it is the last line of the file.  Fix it and you should not see that message.  The .bash_profile runs every time you start the terminal to configure your settings. Keep in mind that files that start with a "." do not show in a directory listing unless you use something like "ls -alt". Hope this helps. Link to showing hidden files in mac finder: http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: @orangeh0g Thank you. I'm a little slow to all this terminal/coding stuff so I apologize for this being a silly question. But that seems to have done the trick. Again, Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help...and we are all in a perpetual state of learning!